Why CPU_SET takes integer instead of unsigned interger as it's first argument?
I know there is CPU_SET(int cpu, cpu_set_t *set) for setting core affinity. According to the signature of this function we can pass also negative numbers as cpu_id to the set of CPUs. Could you please explain what's the point of that? Does that mean there are CPUs with negative IDs or there is another logic/idea behing that?
inline auto setThreadCore(int core_id) noexcept {

  cpu_set_t cpuset;
  CPU_ZERO(&cpuset)
  CPU_SET(core_id, &cpuset)

  return (pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset) == 0);
}


It's very likely that CPU_SET is a macro, not a function. As such it's not really possible to specify the type of its arguments.

At least on glibc the argument is interpreted as size_t.

Making a parameter unsigned doesn't stop you from passing  a negative value. What happens if I assign a negative value to an unsigned variable?

CPU_SETSIZE is 1024 so it doesn't getting an additional bit of space by using an unsigned rather than a signed integer probably doesn't really matter that much

@BoP still, I generally enable -Wsign-conversion (on g++), so that takes care of that. And if things go really crazy, I use boost::numeric_cast to make sure the conversion worked (I don't always do that, because oftentimes you know it's just a type mismatch but the values are perfectly fine)

The man-page states that indices start at zero. A negative index is just as invalid as one beyond the CPU_SETSIZE and is ignored by the same logic. Beyond that, int is often just the default type if it doesn't really matter, in particular because negative integers make good error return values, so keeping that option open for an API is often practised.

related to what BoP said, accidentally passing a negative value is sometimes more easily diagnosed on an int rather than on an unsigned.

@Someprogrammerdude is right: CPU_SET() is documented to be a macro ("The following macros are provided ...").  The manual page does document the expected parameter types as if CPU_SET() were a function, though.  That's confusing, and leaves the question of why the manual is written that way.

On any given system, there are a lot of non-negative values that are incorrect first parameters to CPU_SET(), too.  Asking for an unsigned int instead of an int would more than double the number of those, for no particular advantage.  That valid values for a particular datum will never be negative does not necessarily need to be encoded into the data type with which that datum is represented,

You misunderstand the difference between unsigned int and int.  That is understandable; even the authors of C++ had the same problem.
You think unsigned int means int restricted to non-negative values.  What unsigned int is actually is an integer mod 2^k for some unspecified k (often 32).  Note I used integer here and not int.
int meanwhile is an integer bounded by (inclusively) -2^(k-1) and -1+2^(k-1), with behavior once it leaves that area undefined.
For most purposes, int gives a better experience.  You can do things like "a-b" more often and get a non-surprising answer for modest sized a and b.
When you do this with an unsigned int you get results like a-b > a when both a and b are positive, which is algebraically surprising.
To this end, the C++ committee considers most uses of unsigned in the C++ standard to have been an error.  As a concrete example, it is generally held that std::vector<>.size() should have returned a signed integer.  The benefit of an extra bit of potential size is far overweighed by the insane number of errors it being a modulo-2^32 value has caused.
From this perspective, CPU-id is (a) not a modulo-integer, and (b) unlikely to require more than 2^31 different values (or even 2^15, the smallest limit on int size allowed).  So using int here is probably wise.
